# OSX - Unable to update Android Studio - OutOfMemoryError: Java heap size

Tags: android-studio

Whenever I try to update Android Studio I keep getting the same error. In the past I've had to manually uninstall/download the new build but it's annoying have to do that all the time especially for small updates (minor versions) like this one. Please see attached screenshots to see the problem I'm having

I'm on OSX 10.14.6 Mojave. Everything else is up-to-date. I can see that I'm not running low on free memory either.

Anyone have any idea what's going on? Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Java heap size is set at VM creation time, and has nothing to do with the physical memory available, i. e. it doesn't grow as needed until there's no more virtual memory, the way a native program's heap would.

Go to `Help/Change memory settings`, and increase the heap size as you see fit.

Comment: @seva-alekseyec Hrm.. well now I'm even more confused because I tried to change the memory settings, it says the current value is 1280 and I try to set it to 1920 (which is the default value in the box) and it says changes will only take effect after restart. I click on the button 'save and restart' and after restart the 'current value' is unchanged, still 1280, and the update still fails.. any idea?

Comment: I guess "the current value" is the current heap usage, while the setting is the configured maximum. Set it to, say, 4096, see if that makes a difference.

Comment: that didn't work, changed it to 4096, clicked on 'save and restart' and tried again. It took a long time.. perhaps longer than usual but it failed with the same error